# X11: Detect general Mouse and Keyboard events

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, mouse, x11

Is there a way to detect if the mouse has been moved ANYWHERE on the X Server or a keyboard event occured? I need to react on the user doing anything with the X11 input devices.

I only managed to detect events on my own window using GTK.

I am thankful for every information (it does not have to be full code, an entry point would be good enough!)

Comment: Related question on UNIX.SE (it's not about code however, but it may be possible to look at the source code): https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106736/296692  ■ also looking at `XKeyCheck` source code it uses `XQueryKeymap` (it's inefficient to do polling however)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using the Xinput2 extension. A complete, but rather small, tool which does this for cursor events can be found [here (unclutter-xfixes)](https://github.com/Airblader/unclutter-xfixes). As a disclaimer, I am the author of that tool.

Another good resource in tutorial form can be found [here](http://keithp.com/blogs/Cursor_tracking/).

Using XInput2 has multiple benefits:

- No need to constantly poll the position (resource efficient)
- Does not interfere with / break applications like selecting mouse events on all windows would.

What you *don't* get easily using Xinput2 is the exact position (but you can query it when you need it), but my understanding is that you don't need it anyway.

Once you loaded the extension, which I won't show here, you can select all events like this:

```
XIEventMask masks[1];
unsigned char mask[(XI_LASTEVENT + 7)/8];

memset(mask, 0, sizeof(mask));
XISetMask(mask, XI_RawMotion);
XISetMask(mask, XI_RawButtonPress);
XISetMask(mask, XI_RawKeyPress);

masks[0].deviceid = XIAllMasterDevices;
masks[0].mask_len = sizeof(mask);
masks[0].mask = mask;

XISelectEvents(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), masks, 1);
XFlush(display);
```

In your event queue, you can now look for the corresponding events.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Is there also a way to get the device that produced the input?`For example when I want to block only the devices created by XTEST?

Comment: @Nidhoegger Use `XGetEventData` to get the data from the event and read the extension specification of what this data means. I would assume that you get the information (deviceid), yes, but haven't looked at it. My above mentioned tool, unclutter-xfixes, can show you how to identify the events on the queue and how to call `XGetEventData`. Don't forget to also call `XFreeEventData` afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

For modern X11 implementations, `xinput --test-xi2 --root` will display great detail about all X11 input events available on your root window.  I use this in a shell script that needs to wait on any input event:

```
echo "DEBUG $(date) waiting on X event"
xinput --test-xi2 --root  | head -n 15 >/dev/null
echo "DEBUG $(date) got X event"
```